# Measuring a certain qubit in a three qubit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

Assuming I have a state $|\psi\rangle$ that is a superposition of 3 qubits ($|ijk\rangle\ \ \ \ i,j,k\in\{0,1\}$). When it is said that we measure only the first qubit in, say, the y-axis, does that mean that we apply the operator Y⊗I⊗I on the state $|\psi\rangle$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Measuring the observable $Y \otimes I \otimes I$ is not the same thing as multiplying the state by the unitary operation $Y \otimes I \otimes I$. The measurement snaps the first qubit's state onto its Y axis, whereas the operation rotates the first qubit's state around its Y axis by a half turn.

[Same thing happens with measuring/operating on the Z axis](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22Y%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5Et%22%2C%22Z%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%2C%22Bloch%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image]

Comment: How can I write this mathematically? I'm having a little trouble with the wording now. Say I have an observable A and some state |Ψ>. After the measurement I will get one of the eigenstates |φ_n> with a corresponding coefficient a_n. Is that called measuring the observable A?

Comment: @FlyGuy Some people say a measurement returns the expectation value $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$.  Some people say it gives outcome $a_n$ with probability $p_n=|\langle\psi|\phi_n\rangle|^2$, leaving you with the post-measurement state $|\phi_n\rangle$.  These are the two predominant meanings.  Then, there is also a more general notion of measurement, called POVM measurement.

Comment: I've gone over what was confusing me and now it's clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Measuring the first qubit in Y corresponds to measuring the operator $Y\otimes I \otimes I$, i.e., $\langle\Psi|Y\otimes I\otimes I|\Psi\rangle$.

More generally, doing *anything* (corresponding to some operator $O$) on one qubit within a set of qubits is described by tensoring this operator with the identity on the other qubits.

Comment: So when saying that we're measuring, we're finding an expectation value?

Comment: @FlyGuy You tell me what you mean by measuring.  Just think of a single qubit.  Or is your question about measuring?  Then, you shouldn't talk about three qubits!

Comment: My apologies if I'm unclear, I'm a little confused.

Comment: No need to apologize.  Just ask what you mean to ask.

Comment: I think I have a problem with the wording of things. Let's say I have some state prepared |Ψ>=|0>. Then, if say I apply Z on it, do I say that I'm measuring the qubit in the z-axis?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand what you said in your comment "You tell me what you mean by measuring. Just think of a single qubit. Or is your question about measuring? Then, you shouldn't talk about three qubits!". First, what meanings does measuring have as I'm quite unsure if I understand things correctly now? Second, what did you mean with "Or is your question about measuring? Then, you shouldn't talk about three qubits!"?

Comment: If you do not know what "measuring" is, why don't you ask a question about that in the simplest possible settings? There does not seem to be any need to combine this with 3 qubits.  Ask about a **single** thing you don't understand (or are uncertain about), in the **simplest possible** scenario.

Comment: Ah: And use as many formulas as you can (as opposed to words).

Comment: I think the scenario that I described in my comment above is the simplest. Again, I think my problem right now since I'm confused is with wording. Say I have a single qubit. Simplest case possible -  |0>. What do I call the operation when I do for example Z|0>? If this isn't called a measurement (in the z-axis, I suppose), is this <0|Z|0> (the expectation value) called the measurement? Also, thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you have a different question, you should ask a different question. This should not be done in the comments.  StackExchange is not a discussion board.  (Not saying this is good or bad.)  --  In any case, there is no such thing as "the measurement".  You should define what you mean by "the measurement" in your question.